# How would I logarithmically scale a fraction

Tags: functions, logarithms

I'm trying to convert a decimal, $0 \leq decimal \leq 1$ to another $0\leq weighted \leq 1$.

Such that for $n$ equally spaced fractions, the weighted fractions $\forall1\leq i\leq n: weighted_{\frac{i}{n}}$ become exponentially sparse as they approach 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "exponentially sparse". To divide the unit interval into $n$ pieces that thin out as you near $1$, you could consider division points
$$
x_i = \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^M \quad i = 1, \cdots, n-1
$$
for some large $M$.

Another possibility is to divide the interval into subintervals such that each is $r$ times as large as the preceding one. Then if the first division point is at $x$ you have
$$
x + rx + r^2x + \cdots + r^{n-1}x = 1
$$ 
so
$$
x = \frac{r-1}{r^n - 1} .
$$
Then choose $r$ to find $x$.

For example, if $r = 2$ and $n=3$ the division points are at $1/7$ and $3/7$ giving intervals of length $1/7, 2/7, 4/7$.

Comment: I don't really get this answer. I'm looking for a bijective function from [0,1] -> [0,1] such that linearly distributed numbers become exponentially distributed after being scaled

Comment: My second answer is the same as @YvesDaoust .

Answer (score 2):

If the $x$ are uniformly spaced, then the $a^x$ are exponentially spaced.

The interval $[0,1]$ maps to $[1,a]$, and you can (linearly) rescale to $[0,1]$ as

$$\frac{a^x-1}{a-1}.$$